# Unable to add style to the dynamically created button properly

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically adding  Style to the dynamically created button named **ordernow**

Depending on the status field i am adding a style to  the button

As per the requirement

If the status is 1 the class should be

```
btn-success
```

If the status is 0 the class must be

```
btn-mrn
```

I have tried this way

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var classstyle  = "";

    if(response[i].status==1) {
        classstyle = "success";
    } else {
        classstyle = "mrn";
    }

    var $ordernow= $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button',name:'btn1', class:'btn btn-'+classstyle+'', value:'Order Now', style: 'float:right'});
    divhtml.append('<li><h6>' + response[i].area + '</h6><p>' + response[i].address + '</p></li>');

}
```

But i observed that,  whatever the last style is present that is being added to all the buttons

http://jsfiddle.net/nvx4tkLt/5/

Could anybody please help how to resolve this

Comment: Can you simplify your fiddle to just the relevant part? It's difficult to even figure out even where the code in question gets called or what it's supposed to do.

Comment: In order to simulate the response from server i have used those arrays , and this status checking is present under  showRestaurantDetailsByLocation function .

Comment: You can still simplify it - you have a lot of stuff in there that isn't at all relevant. Also use the "TidyUp" button and your problem actually becomes obvious. You have this line `divhtml.children("li").append($ordernow);` outside of your loop, but `$ordernow` is constructed inside the loop. So you are only ever adding the `$ordernow` that was constructed in the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you are adding `$ordernow` outside of your loop, so you are only ever adding the button that was constructed in the last iteration through the loop. To fix it, try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

    var classstyle = "";
    if (response[i].status == 1) {
        classstyle = "success";
    } else {
        classstyle = "mrn";
    }

    var $ordernow = $('<input/>').attr({
        type: 'button',
        name: 'btn1',
        class: 'btn btn-' + classstyle + '',
        value: 'Order Now',
        style: 'float:right'
    });

    divhtml.append('<li><h6>' + response[i].area + '</h6><p>' + response[i].address + 
       '</p></li>').append($ordernow);  // <-- note we are appending inside the loop now
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/nvx4tkLt/4/

Comment: Excellent exactly what i needed and sorry for the messy code i didn't knew the feature Tidy Up till now .Thanks once again sir .